# EditText gets pushed off screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, fragment, android-softkeyboard

I have screen with `NestedScrollView` with vertical `LinearLayout` containing Fragment, `Recycler` and another Fragment. When I click and focus `EditText` in one of the Recycler's items, soft keyboard pops up and pushes it off screen. `windowSoftInputMode` is set to `stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize` for the activity.

Did anyone encounter this problem before?

**Layout:**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    >
    <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      >
      <com.trinerdis.skypicker.widget.SupportFragmentLayout
        android:id="@+id/first_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/middle_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        />
      <com.trinerdis.skypicker.widget.SupportFragmentLayout
        android:id="@+id/second_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_medium"
        />
      <include
        android:id="@+id/info"
        layout="@layout/layout_info"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
  </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</layout>
```

Comment: Add relevant code in question. This is not enough information.

Comment: Android works badly with multiple nested scrollable layouts, you should move the recyclerview (which is a scrollable layout) outside the NestedScrollView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't try ALL the options as I thought and the issue got fixed by changing `windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"` to `windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"`